# HTTP Rest request generator scripting tool

Tags: rest, http, testing, selenium, automation

I am looking for a tool that lets me automate REST requests. I want to perform simple load test
where in I need to send request to my server continuously.

I looked at Selenium but I didnt find a way to continuously send requests, may be I am wrong.
Please let me know if somebody knows any tool like selenium which will help me to loop 
my RESTrequests.

Thanks in advance for any sort of help.

Br,
Rohit PAI

Comment: Try jmeter, its simple and easy to use http://jmeter.apache.org/

Answer (score 4):

For basic load testing, and something that you can script, check out ApacheBench. It comes stock with the Apache web server. If you're at the command line on a *nix machine (Mac OS, Linux, etc.) try running: "man ab"

You can write a simple shell script that you can put into the background that loops continuously, or you can cron it up, so that it runs on a schedule. Now, that's a cheap and simple way to perform load tests with configurable request concurrency and basic performance statistics when it's complete.

Now, if you're looking for automated testing/monitoring of a REST API that supports assertions and multi-step requests that allow you to pass variables from one test to the next, as well as scheduling and reporting, try Runscope. You can run tests for REST APIs in the cloud or even endpoints on your local network / VPC (useful if your'e testing behind firewall on dev / staging environments). https://runscope.com